# Can i use google api without using login popup?

Tags: javascript, .net-core, angular6

That means i want to use email and password my application then post to google API.Google API login authentication and save my browser.

Comment: Which Google API you want to use ? e.g. Maps, Drive .. ?

Comment: i want to use youtube api